# Scroll pane in JFrame not showing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollpane

I try to put a scroll bar on a frame but it's not working, I don't see the scroll bar.

This my code :

```
Popup noticePopup = new Popup("Notice", 1500, 900);
JPanel noticePanel = new JPanel();
noticePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1500,1000));
List<List> ListNote = controller.Medicament.consultationNotice(medocSelectStr);
String noticeThis =null;
for(int n=0;n<ListNote.size();n++) {
    noticeThis = (String) ListNote.get(n).get(1);
}
JTextArea noticeArea = new JTextArea(noticeThis);
noticePopup.add(noticePanel);
noticePanel.add(noticeArea);
JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane( noticePanel);
// only a configuration to the jScrollPane...
jScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
jScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

// Then, add the jScrollPane to your frame
noticePopup.getContentPane().add(jScrollPane);

JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(noticePanel,ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
noticePopup.getContentPane().add(scroll);
```

Comment: Constructor for class `javax.swing.Popup` is protected. How are you calling it? Also, class `javax.swing.Popup` does not have a `getContentPane()` method. Does the code you posted compile? Or is `Popup` in the code you posted not referring to `javax.swing.Popup`?

Answer (score 1):

You're creating two scrollpanes with the same content:

```
 JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane( noticePanel);
```

and:

```
JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(noticePanel,ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

And you're adding both of them to the popup and you're also adding the noticepanel to the popup, so there's a lot of code that needs to be removed

```
                Popup noticePopup = new Popup("Notice", 1500, 900);
                JPanel noticePanel = new JPanel();
                noticePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1500,1000));
                List<List> ListNote = controller.Medicament.consultationNotice(medocSelectStr);
                String noticeThis =null;
                for(int n=0;n<ListNote.size();n++) {
                    noticeThis = (String) ListNote.get(n).get(1);
                }
                JTextArea noticeArea = new JTextArea(noticeThis);
                noticePanel.add(noticeArea);

                JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(noticePanel,ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
                noticePopup.getContentPane().add(scroll);
```

Comment: I know it's because i tried all this solutions and it's not showing, it was only to show you what iI tried but your solution is not working too....

Comment: Can you please post a SSCCE (http://sscce.org/)? We don't know what the Popup class is, also the controller.Medicament call is probably irrelevant because it just produces a String apparently

Answer (score 1):

I see many potential problems:

```
Popup noticePopup = new Popup("Notice", 1500, 900);
JPanel noticePanel = new JPanel();
noticePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1500,1000));
```

Don't attempt to manually code the size of a frame or panel:

1. you don't know what resolution people will be using
2. the numbers your provide make no sense. The width of the panel can't be the same as the frame because the frame has borders. The height can't be different by 100 because the panel will be expanded to fill the space available.

If you want the frame to fill the screen then you simply use:

```
noticePopup.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

What do you expect the following code to do:

```
for (int n=0; n < ListNote.size(); n++) 
{
    noticeThis = (String) ListNote.get(n).get(1);
}
```

if you have more than one item in the List then you simply replace the text in the "noticeThis" variable with the last item in the list.

Instead you should be appending the text to the text area:

```
JTextArea noticeArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);

for (int n = 0; n < ListNote.size(); n++) 
{
    if (n > 0 ) noticeArea.append("\n");

    noticeArea.append( (String)ListNote.get(n).get(1) );
}
```

Why do you have a "noticePanel":

```
noticePanel.add(noticeArea);
JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(noticePanel, ...);
noticePopup.getContentPane().add(scroll);
```

By default a JPanel uses a FlowLayout which will respect the preferred size of any component added to it. I have no idea what the preferred size of the text area is but the scrollbars will only appear when the preferred size of the component is greater than the size of the scrollpane.

Just add the text area directly to the scrollpane and scrollbars will appear as needed:

```
JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(noticeArea, ...);
noticePopup.add(scroll);
```

Note you don't need to use `getContentPane()` since JDK1.4.